# htaccess - 301 redirect removing part of url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm not able to get to work this 301 redirect, i have to remove "BeTa" word from all the request, and redirect: 
`FROM: 
http://www.example.com/BeTa/other/content 
TO: 
http://www.example.com/other/content`

"BeTa" could also be present in other part of url: 
`FROM: 
http://www.example.com/bla/BeTa/other/content
TO: 
http://www.example.com/bla/other/content`

is it possible?
Right now I have only tried the first part:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/BeTa/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tweak your regex to match `BaTa` anywhere like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?BeTa(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: This has worked well on my testing. Make sure this is first rule after `RewriteEngine on` and .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Sorry, i was not working because "BeTa" folder actually exists. If i remove that folder, it works. One more thing, there is a way to remove double slash too?

Comment: how i could integrate this, with this existing .htaccess from wordpress?
http://pastebin.com/R94pYhaX

Comment: Place this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line.