# rewrite rule forward one url to another wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using wordpress

I would like to forward one url to another preferably via wordpress  like add_rewrite_rule() but as I know it is not possible. (Because it will be much easier.)

I have few cases that I want to match with same rule

I would like to forward

http://dom.com/sale/product to http://dom.com/product

http://dom.com/sale/hierachicalproduct/product to http://dom.com/hierachicalproduct/product

http://localhost/dom.com/sale/product to http://localhost/dom.com/product

http://localhost/dom.com/sale/hierachicalproduct/product to http://localhost/dom.com/hierachicalproduct/product

I want to remove "**/sale**" rest will be same.

I do not want to type single rule for every case.

This is the code that I used but problem is this code forwarding like

http://localhost/dom.com/sale/product to http://localhost/product 
it is skipping **/dom.com** side

```
RewriteRule ^sale/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011358/htaccess-301-redirect-removing-part-of-url

Comment: @hardiksolanki   This is working same as my rule. It removes dom.com

Comment: Can you please copy your full `.htaccess` code?

Comment: @hardiksolanki here is http://jsfiddle.net/zt9k4k6o/

Comment: Give it try with `RewriteRule ^/sale/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`.

Comment: **RewriteRule ^/sale/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]** is not forwarding

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess placed in root directory?

Comment: @anubhava the `.htaccess` file isn't in the root on localhost (and I think that is the problem). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544333/rewrite-rule-forward-one-url-to-another-wordpress/30544558?noredirect=1#comment49162638_30544558)

Comment: Hmm it is a case where on localhost .htaccess is in `http://localhost/dom.com/` but on production host it is on `http://dom.com/` path. Let me see if I can think of something.

Comment: @anubhava this is exacly as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work from .htaccess in `http://localhost/dom.com/` on localhost and `http://dom.com/` on production host.

```
RewriteEngine On

# get rewrite base dynamically
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

RewriteRule ^sale/(.+)$ %{ENV:BASE}$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make sure these rules are first rules below `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: This is incredible. Working awesome. Does it cost to the server to much. Because realy hard work.

Comment: Nope, this is pretty simple stuff for Apache web server, no additional load.

Comment: Thank you for your effords. I appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code after `RewriteEngine On`

So your code should be

I can see n your .htaccess file below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domain.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /akasiayachting.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Just put below code after `RewriteBase /domain.com/` this line

```
RewriteRule ^/sale/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This not worked. Here is my permalink structure if helps http://localhost/dom.com/%postname%

Comment: unfortunately it is not working as well. Here is my last code http://jsfiddle.net/axskqx3d/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using two capturing groups:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)sale/(.*)$ /$1$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code also forward http://localhost/dom.com/sale/product to http://localhost/product

Comment: That's strange. The dom.com part _should_ be captured by the first group.

Comment: I tried with @hardiksolanki advices also but not success.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is **where** you have put your `.htaccess` file. On localhost, which directory do you have it in? It will need to be in the root for my rule to work. I'm guessing you have it inside the `/dom.com/` directory which won't work.

Comment: my .htacces inside of http://localhost/dom.com/.htaccess with all wordpress files. It is forwarding properly for all cases except of this one.

Comment: For my rule to work, it'll need to be in `localhost/.htaccess`

Comment: I see @henrywright but my all web sites works like this. It is so hard to change. I should solve this via mod rewrite.