# 301 redirect using only part of original url

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard, redirect

I am trying to 301 redirect some url from my old site structure to my new simpler site structure.

My original urls are formatted: /my-place-name-33/ for example, which I need to redirect to just /my-place-name/ completely omitting the -33

I tired adapting the solution from this thread: [htaccess - 301 redirect removing part of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011358/htaccess-301-redirect-removing-part-of-url) but my separator isn't strong enough (if that makes sense). I only have a hyphen to separate, but in most cases on the site, the my-place-name already contains hyphens.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get around this. Any help would be amazing.

Many thanks

D

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this simple approch should do what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)-\d+/?$ /$1/ [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! No 500 error, I just appended [R=301,L] and it works great. I know this isn't the ideal way of doing this, but on this particular server I have little choice. Many thanks for your help... hair implants are probably very expensive  :)

Comment: OK, just for the sake of completeness: when using an external redirection, neither the `END` nor the `L` flag are required, since the external redirection obviously immediately terminates the internal rewriting. It was not clear from your question that you were referring to two separate systems.